# how to multiply (or sum) the dropdown box value that retrieved from mysql database

Tags: php, html

I am stuck on the dropdown box value calculation. anyone can help me on this problem ?

I have two dropdown boxes on my webpage, and the values that in the dropdown boxes are retrived from the mysql database.

Dropdown box `A` displays two different values, which are `Chassise_Name` and `Chassise_price`, and The dropdown box `B` displays the quantity of the item.

```
    Dropdown box "A"                      Dropdown box "B"
SuperServer 7036A-T(Black)    $90                    3
```

`Superserver 7036A-T(Black)` is retrieved from the `Chassis_Name`;
`$90` is retrieved from the `chassis_Price`;
`3` is retrieved from the Quantity in other table.

**Question:**
How can I take only the price on the dropdown box `A` multiply the number in the dropdown box `B`?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "users", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("a4202648_wang") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Chassis_Name, Chassis_Price FROM Chassis where Chassis_Form_Factor='ATX'") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo '<select name="Chassis" onChange="change()">'; 
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo '<option Name="Chassis">',$row['Chassis_Name'],' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$row['Chassis_Price'],'&nbsp;','</option>'; 
} 
echo '</select>';
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";

$result= mysql_query("SELECT Number FROM Quantity") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo '<select name="Quantity" Value="Quantity" onChange="change()" >'; 

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result)) {
      // Print out the contents of each row into a table
      echo '<option Name="Quantity">',$row['Number'],'</option>'; 
} 
echo '</select>';
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you want to multiply the value from a and b?  Is this after each is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the code a bit for readability but you'll want to add id="chassis" and id="quantity" so that you can reference that dom object when doing your summation.
Be sure to put the `<script>` in the head of your document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready( function() {
        function change() {
            var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
            var chassis = $('#chassis').val();
            var sum = quantity * chassis;
            $('#the_sum').val(sum);
        }
    });
</script>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<?php
  echo '<select id="chassis" name="Chassis" onChange="change()">'; 

  echo '<option value="{$row['Chassis_Name']}">{$row['Chassis_Name']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Chassis_Price']}&nbsp;</option>'; 

  echo '<select id="quantity" name="Quantity" Value="Quantity" onChange="change()" >';
  echo '<option value="{$row['Number']}">{$row['Number']}</option>';

?>
<input type="text" value="" id="the_sum" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```